# How to get java version without java updater using powershell?

Tags: java, regex, powershell

To find java version , i run the below command.

It returns both Java 8 and Java auto updater. I would like to get Java version alone. I can't hard code the version as in some machines different version may be present.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Product -Filter "Name like '%java%'"

Name             Caption                             Vendor                             Version                            IdentifyingNumber                 
----             -------                             ------                             -------                            -----------------                 
Java 8 Update... Java 8 Update 171                   Oracle Corporation                 8.0.1710.11                        {26A56AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F3218...
Java Auto Upd... Java Auto Updater                   Oracle Corporation                 2.8.171.11                         {4A03863F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748...
```

How to get Java version through filter?

Comment: why not just run `java -v`?

Comment: @lino the cmdlet will return the object but java -version will return string then i have to parse it.

Comment: Community expects to see your attempts.

Comment: Here what "parsing it" means: `java -version |& head -n1 | cut -f3 -d" "`

Comment: you may want to use a pipe `|` and then just select the version with: `| % {$_.Version}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to increase the specificity of the Filter. One way we can do that is by excluding anything where the name is like 'Auto', as any Java RE installation won't have the word 'Auto' in it, but the Auto Updater does.

Like so:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Product -Filter "Name LIKE '%Java%' AND NOT Name LIKE '%Auto%'"
```

By using `AND` in the filter, you can add another condition to the filter. To reverse the `LIKE` condition (*not like*) you start the condition with `NOT`, then add the condition after that - `Name LIKE '%x%'`

This should give the result you are looking for, where you have a PowerShell Object to use and only the item you want within that result set.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the first entry of the result and Select the `Version` Property:

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Product -Filter "Name like '%java%'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version)[0]
```

To get the same output but with expanding the Filter instead of adressing the place in the array (shown by @Adam Parsons):

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Product -Filter "Name LIKE '%Java%' AND NOT Name LIKE '%Auto%'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version
```